# SDK_ERROR At least one participant (other than self is required)

Tags: circuit-sdk

Hi Once I fill the contact form in and press the submit button i'm getting the following error, can anyone provide any assistance?

```
            Error creating new complaint Error
                at new circuit.Error (C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\node_modules\circuit-sdk\circuit.js:311:22)
                at C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\node_modules\circuit-sdk\circuit.js:55977:28
                at new Promise (<anonymous>)
                at Object.createGroupConversation (C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\node_modules\circuit-sdk\circuit.js:55966:20)
                at Object.createConversation (C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\circuit.js:23:19)
                at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\server.js:78:32)
                at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
                at C:\Users\chrisconnolly\customer-support\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:513:12
                at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9) {
              code: 'SDK_ERROR',
              message: 'At least one participant (other than self) is required',
              stack: 'Error\n    at new circuit.Error ' +
                '(C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\node_modules\\circuit-sdk\\circuit.js:311:22)\n' +
                '    at ' +
                'C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\node_modules\\circuit-sdk\\circuit.js:55977:28\n' +
                '    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at ' +
                'Object.createGroupConversation ' +
                '(C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\node_modules\\circuit-sdk\\circuit.js:55966:20)\n' +
                '    at Object.createConversation ' +
                '(C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\circuit.js:23:19)\n    at ' +
                'Socket.<anonymous> ' +
                '(C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\server.js:78:32)\n    at ' +
                'Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)\n    at ' +
                'C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\customer-support\\node_modules\\socket.io\\lib\\socket.js:513:12\n' +
                '    at processTicksAndRejections ' +
                '(internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions on specific example apps are better post in their respective repo's issues page. I.e. https://github.com/circuit/customer-support/issues

Now looking at the error you get, it says "server.js:78" (https://github.com/circuit/customer-support/blob/master/server.js#L78) which is the createConversation API. And given the error says "At least one participant (other than self) is required", I suspect you are not passing any users as first parameter. Looking at https://github.com/circuit/customer-support/blob/master/server.js#L54 shows that those supportUsers come from the config file "config.json".

Did you rename config.json.template to config.json as per instructions in the README? And did you edit the config file (https://github.com/circuit/customer-support/blob/master/config.json.template#L26) with those support users?